# Python schedule, do tasks in parallel

Tags: python, schedule

I have scheduled my tasks using [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    channel_crawler(priority=1)
    schedule.every(PRIORITY[1]["interval"]).minutes.do(channel_crawler, priority=1)

    schedule.every().day.at("17:30").do(distance_fixer)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

`channel_crawler` takes about `5 minutes` to run and `distance_fixer` takes about `5 hours`. when I run my code while running the `distance_fixer`, the schedule does not run `channel_crawler` every `10 minutes`. How can I run my functions in parallel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use multiprocessing for the job, so each process run each function

```
def run_schedule():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

def run_crawler_schedule():
    channel_crawler(priority=1)
    schedule.every(PRIORITY[1]["interval"]).minutes.do(channel_crawler, priority=1)
    run_schedule(schedule)

def run_fix():
    schedule.every().day.at("17:30").do(distance_fixer)
    run_schedule()


def run_job()
    p = Process(target=run_crawler_schedule)
    c = Process(target=run_fix)
    p.start()
    c.start()
    p.join()
    c.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_job()
```